# Null Point Exception - Android Volley Response

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-volley

I have the following code below working but I do not know how to make the following object (**responseCurrentConditionsClassObject**) available on the onCreateView method without getting a null point exception error?

```
        public class PlaceCurrentFragment extends Fragment {
        private static final String ARG_CITYID = "cityid";

        private String mCityId;

        // String used to indicate the title on a ViewPager
        public final String PAGERTABTITLE = "Now";
        private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

        // Tag for logging possible errors onto the Log
        private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        public static final String DOMAIN = "http://api.openweathermap.org";
        public static final String ENDPOINT = "/data/2.5/weather?";
        public static final String CITYIDPARAMETER = "id=";
        public static final String APPIDPARAMETER = "&appid=someapinumber";

        Gson gson;
        ResponseCurrentConditions responseCurrentConditionsClassObject;

        public PlaceCurrentFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param cityid Parameter 1.
         * @return A new instance of fragment PlaceCurrentFragment.
         */
        public static PlaceCurrentFragment newInstance(String cityid) {
            PlaceCurrentFragment fragment = new PlaceCurrentFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(ARG_CITYID, cityid);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (getArguments() != null) {
                mCityId = getArguments().getString(ARG_CITYID);
            }


            // Shows message to user while makeJsonObjectRequest() is still running.
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting weather forecast...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);

            // Make JSON request
            makeJsonObjectRequest(mCityId);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_place_current, container, false);
            TextView mCityIdTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.city_id);
            // NULL POINT EXCEPTION HERE!!
            mCityIdTextView.setText(responseCurrentConditionsClassObject.getName()); 

            return view;
        }

        public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
                mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                        + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();
            mListener = null;
        }

        /**
         * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
         * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
         * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
         * activity.
         * <p/>
         * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
         * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
         * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
         */
        public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
            void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
        }

        /**
         * Method to make json object request
         */
        private void makeJsonObjectRequest(final String cityId) {

            // Show dialog while the request is made
            showpDialog();
            String URL = DOMAIN + ENDPOINT + CITYIDPARAMETER + cityId + APPIDPARAMETER;

            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                    URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    // Log response
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                    String responseString = new String(String.valueOf(response));
                    gson = new Gson();

                    // **PROBLEM WITH THIS OBJECT BEING ACCESSIBLE ON onCreateView() METHOD**
                    responseCurrentConditionsClassObject = gson.fromJson(responseString, ResponseCurrentConditions.class);

                    hidepDialog();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    // Warn user
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                            "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    // hide the progress dialog
                    hidepDialog();
                }
            });
            // Adding request to request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
        }

        /**
         * Method for showing dialog
         */
        private void showpDialog() {
            if (!pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Method for hiding dialog
         */
        private void hidepDialog() {
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

If I try to access the object on the onCreateView() method as show below I get a null exception error.

```
responseCurrentConditionsClassObject.getName();
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this related to the asynchronous aspect of the volley request at makeJsonObjectRequest where the object may not be ready or null at the point when it's called or is it something simpler that I'm missing? Any detailed feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see the error, no logcat needed, is there a nullabel field in the ResponseCurrentConditions.class??, are all the key/vals in the responseString correct mapped to the class??

Comment: @Xoce ... hi, yes it is correctly mapped. I can access it on inside the onResponse method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you hit this line: 
`mCityIdTextView.setText(responseCurrentConditionsClassObject.getName());`

The volley request hasn't returned a response yet.

What you can do is put that line of code into the `onResponse` of the volley request.

First make `mCityIdTextView` a member variable.

```
public class PlaceCurrentFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView mCityIdTextView;
    // etc
```

Then "find" it in `onCreateView`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_place_current, container, false);
    mCityIdTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.city_id);
    return view;
}
```

Finally in `onResponse`:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

    // Log response
    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

    String responseString = new String(String.valueOf(response));
    gson = new Gson();

    responseCurrentConditionsClassObject = gson.fromJson(responseString, ResponseCurrentConditions.class);

    mCityIdTextView.setText(responseCurrentConditionsClassObject.getName());

    hidepDialog();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution has worked. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

We need to see more information like the responseString and the ResponseCurrentConditions class..

but we can emit a diagnostic+ suggestions with out it....

Your application has a `onCreate` and a `onCreateView`, the order of the call in the lifecycle is ok, so the method `makeJsonObjectRequest(mCityId);` is called before the `onCreateView`, which is good.

The problem is a NullPointer exception and the cause is because you have the object ResponseCurrentConditions wich is either null or it holds null fields( the name field for example)

Debug your application and verify if

1. the hole ResponseCurrentConditions object is null
2. if not null, if the field name is null
3. if condition1 is met, then verify the ResponseCurrentConditions.class and be sure that the json string in the `responseString` is mapped properly to all the necesary members of the class.

Comment: Thanks for the input Xoce. In the end it was a simple problem of not catching the object properly as MidasLefko mentioned.